# script to check file available if yes then send email or do nothing

Tags: email, powershell

I have a batch script & a PowerShell script which sends me email as per schedule.

The batch script is as:-
it goes on the the SFTP location login's in with the required credentials goes to the specific path & gives me an output of files available on the SFTP folder to a text file on local machine. This is working fine.

The PowerShell script:-
this script reads the outfile file & sends the last one line in an email body.

My issue is:-
When the output is missing in content, the powershell script still runs & sends me a blank email.

I am looking for a script were it will read the output file & send email & if the output file is empty, it will do nothing.

Comment: I wouldn't want any output-file to begin with if there was no new stuff to process. If the output file never gets deleted and only has additional information appended to it then there should always be a last line.

Answer (score 1):

before reading the output file, you can simply check its length, eg.

```
if(!(get-item output.txt).length){exit}
```

Comment: This is the Powershell script

$fromaddress = "xxx@xxx.com"
$toaddress = "xxx@xxx.com"
$bccaddress = ""
$CCaddress =  ""
$Subject = "File Name File $((get-date).adddays(0).toshortdatestring())"
$Body = Get-Content C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\xxx\Filename.TXT | Select-Object -last 1
$smtpserver = "xxx.xxx.com"

Comment: $message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.From = $fromaddress
$message.To.Add($toaddress)
$message.CC.Add($CCaddress)
$message.Bcc.Add($bccaddress)
$message.IsBodyHtml = $False
$message.Subject = $Subject
$message.body = $body
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver)
$smtp.Send($message)